# How to select from WebMatrix-database in Visual Studio with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, razor, webmatrix

How we select data from SDF (webmatrix) database in visual studio with Linq just like we can with northwind, like this:?

```
// Northwnd inherits from System.Data.Linq.DataContext.
Northwnd nw = new Northwnd(@"northwnd.mdf");
// or, if you are not using SQL Server Express
// Northwnd nw = new Northwnd("Database=Northwind;Server=server_name;Integrated Security=SSPI");

var companyNameQuery =
    from cust in nw.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust.CompanyName;

foreach (var customer in companyNameQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer);
}
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399398.aspx

please thank you for your help.

Comment: '.sdf' is for SQL Server Compact Edition databases. WebMatrix is an IDE. Are you saying you created your SQLCE database in WebMatrix?

Comment: I sure am. And I imported the website into Visual Studio Ultimate and am continuing from within Visual Studio now, @TiesonT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Linq To SQL is officially supported with SQL Server CE 4.0, although [it appears you can get it working](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-linq-to-sql-with-sql-server.html). Microsoft's recommended approach is to use the Entity Framework.

I've written a couple of articles on using EF with SQL Server CE in WebMatrix. One covers the [Code First approach](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/182/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Development-With-WebMatrix), and the other [looks at a database first approach](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/185/Building-A-Razor-Web-Pages-Site-With-Database-First-And-Entity-Framework).

Comment: Awesome article, Mike. Thanks a trillion.